# Nested SQL query searching the wrong table (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, inner-join

I have two tables:

- `devices` : (id (int), type(int))
- `devices_log` : (id (int), device_id (int) (FK), data(string), date(string))

The type is a number between **1 and 10**, the data column should be a number between **1 and 100** ("1", ..., "100") or **"emptyX"** (the **X** represents any character from **"a" to "z"**)

The device which has the type 9 always has a number in the data column.

I need to update the data field for all the **"type 9"** devices which 
**have a data bigger than 50 so that ==> data = data /2.**

I've started with an `INNER JOIN` :

```
select l.id 
from devices_log l 
inner join (select id from devices where type = 9) d on (l.device_id = d.id)
```

This statement returns all the logs for "type 9" devices, but when I add the where condition :

```
select l.id 
from devices_log l 
inner join (select id from devices where type = 9) d on (l.device_id = d.id) 
where cast(data as INTEGER) > 50
```

I got this error :

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "emptyG"

I've also tried so many statements that lead to the same error :

```
select id
from devices_log 
where device_id in (select id from devices where type = 9) 
and cast(data as integer) > 50

select id from
(
  select id, device_id, cast (devices_log.data as integer) as int_data 
  from devices_log 
  join devices on (devices_log.device_id = devices.id
) and type = 9) ccs where ccs.int_data > 50
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL queries describe the result set, not the specific steps being taken.  I actually thought this problem didn't appear in Postgres (I've seen it in other databases).  I would start with this version:

```
select l.id
from devices_log l inner join
     devices d 
     on l.device_id = d.id
where d.type = 9 and cast(l.data as INTEGER) > 50 ;
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, then you can fix this with a `case` in the `where`:

```
select l.id
from devices_log l inner join
     devices d 
     on l.device_id = d.id
where d.type = 9 and
      (case when d.type = 9 then cast(l.data as INTEGER) end) > 50 ;
```

The `case` should not evaluate the `then` unless the condition is true.